# Function to copy names from a file into a char * array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

As part of my program I need to copy individual names from a file into an array defined as `char *Names[NumOfNames]`, where `NumOfNames` is an integer that holds the total number of names in the file. I am new to pointers to arrays and this seems to be where my trouble is.

The file is written in the following format:

> JohnFrankJamesPeter

(i.e. Each name begins with a capital letter and there are no spaces between the names)

Here is my unfinished function so far:

```
void LoadNamesIntoArray()
{
    char ch;
    int NumOfNames = 0;

    FILE *fpn = fopen(NamesFilePath, "r+");

    if (fpn == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading. \n", NamesFilePath);
        printf("Set up Names file at %s and restart. \n", NamesFilePath);
        perror("Error opening Names file");
    }

    do{
        ch = fgetc(fpn);
        if(isupper(ch)){
            NumOfNames++;
        }
    }while(ch != EOF);

    char *Names[NumOfNames];
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have tried several ways to copy each name into each element of the array using the `fgets` function and the `islower()` function to recognize when to move onto the next element of the Names array.

I would like the array to be in such a way that

```
printf("%s", Names[0])
```

would print "John" and so on. Is this possible? Any help or assistance as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am now messing around trying to copy each name into a temporary array and then into each element of `char *Names[NumOfNames}`. However, to test if the file was being copied correctly into the temporary array, I tried to print it out, but it isn't printing correctly. Here is the block of code:

```
do{
    ch = fgetc(fpn);
    TempName[i] = ch;
    i++;
}while(ch != EOF);

for(i = 0; i<15; i++){
    printf("%c", TempName[i]);
}
```

I know that this would print out the first 15 characters and not a single name, but my problem is that it is printing all the strange symbols rather than the actual letters.

Comment: `ch` should have type `int`. Otherwise you can't compare it against `EOF`. The reason `fgetc()` returns `int` instead of `char` is specifically to get some extra range for an `EOF` value that doesn't overlap a valid `char` value.

Comment: Note that char *Names[n] gives you n pointers to strings but it does not also give you n strings. To do that you would have to allocate the strings individually. So, you should probably read characters one at a time into a buffer until you hit the end of a name, then zero-terminate that buffer, then allocate/copy it using Names[count++] = strdup(buffer). Repeat in a loop until you are done.

Comment: It would be easier if you know the maximum length of *one* name. Do you know it?

Comment: there are a lot of names in the file so I do not know it, they are all definitely less than 15 anyway. From a quick scan, the longest I could see was 12.

Comment: Is there a newline at the end of the list of names?

Comment: fgetc() returns an int, no a char.  so 'ch' needs to be declared as an int  EOF is an int (0xFFFFFFFF) so to compare against EOF, 'ch' must be an int

Comment: there seems to be missing a setting of the names array to actually point to some memory..  The usual method: names = malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAX_NAMES ); memset( names, 0x00, sizeof(char*)*MAX_NAMES)l  for(int i = 0; i<MAX_NAMES; i++)  { names[i] = malloc( MAX_NAME_LENGTH);   Of course, always check each malloc returned value to not be == NULL and remember, in the end (or any error) to free all the malloc'd areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good first step, finding the number of names.

Add to it a determination of the max length.

```
size_t MaxLength = 0;
size_t CurentLength = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fpn)) != EOF) {
  if(isupper(ch)){
    CurrentLength = 0; 
    NumOfNames++;
  }
  CurentLength++;
  if (CurrentLength > MaxLength) {
    MaxLength = CurrentLength; 
  }
}
```

Rewind file, allocate  buffers.

```
rewind(fpn);
char *Buffer = malloc(MaxLength + 1);
// +1 here to deal with files that do not begin with  A-Z
char **Names = malloc((NumOfNames + 1) * sizeof *Names);
```

Then read names again and allocate space for each name using `strdup()`.  [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) is not standard C, but is standard in POSIX and therefore commonly available - see below.

```
size_t i = 0;
size_t name_index = 0;
for(;;)  {
  ch = fgetc(fpn);
  if (ch == EOF || isupper(ch)) {
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    if (i > 0) Names[name_index++] = strdup(buffer);
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    i = 0;
  }
  buffer[i++] = ch;
}
```

---

[Edit]

Sample `strdup()` implementation.

```
char *strdup(const char *str) {
  size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
  char *copy = malloc(len);
  if (copy) {
    memcpy(copy, str, len);
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that reading a file twice can be somewhere between expensive and impossible — if the file is gigabytes in size or is actually connected to a terminal, pipe or socket.  For actual student exercises, the sizes are seldom so large as to cause trouble.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Agree about the impossible part if the rewind fails.  Fortunately, OP's code needs to handle "names from a file".

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the max size of each name is 15 you could do something like this :

```
char buf[15];
int i = 0;
do {
    if ((ch = fgetc(fpn)) == EOF) break;
    buf[i++] = ch;
    if (isupper(ch)) {
        Names[NumOfNames] = malloc(i * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(Names[NumOfNames]), buf, i -1);
        i = 0;
        NumOfNames++;
    }
} while(ch != EOF);
```

Else you'd have to use realloc rather than the buf[15].

Comment: `Names[NumOfNames] = malloc(i * sizeof(char)); ... Names[NumOfNames][i] = '\0';` writes past the memory allocated to `Names[NumOfNames]`.  ` -1` in `strncpy()` is suspicious.  Since code know array length, suggest `memcpy()`.

Comment: You might note that now you could, probably should, replace the `do … while` loop with `while ((ch = fgetc(fpn)) != EOF)`, which is the normal form for a loop.  After the loop, you need to process the tail of the last name — add the trailing null and increment the counter; that's an area where the question is a mess too.  Also, `strncpy()` will only return null if its first argument is null; the `if` and `perror()` are not necessary.  Also note that `perror()` does not exit; your code would continue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, was just keeping the do...while, cause that's how the OP had framed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly is it just strange symbols. A string is the letters of the name and the nul byte '\0', not to be confused with NULL. This means the name John needs 5 char positions [0,3] for letters and '\0' in 4.

At no point are you stamping the end of the array with the nul byte.

The best way to do this whole problem is to measure the file, create the array, rewind the file then process it putting the letters into the array stamping '\0' at the end of each.

The best way to print the first 15 of a string is

```
printf("%15s",tmpname) ;
```

Comment: `printf("%15s","12345678901234567890") ;` --> `12345678901234567890`.  The 15 in `"%15s"` insures output is at least 15 `char` wide, padding with `' '` as needed.

Comment: Yeah you right, my bad. The only way is this 2 liner.    string[15]='\0';    printf("%s",string);

Comment: %.15s rather than %15s?

Comment: Disagree with "The _only_ way is this 2 liner"  and agree with @jarmod `printf("%.15s","12345678901234567890") ;` --> `123456789012345`.

Comment: Does the '.' mean exactly. Can you use it with numbers like ".3%d"

Comment: The number after `.` has various meanings per specifier.  A lone number or a number before `.` has a uniform meaning of minimum width to print.

Comment: Note that the `.3` in `.3%d` are just two literal characters to be printed; they're not part of a conversion specification.  The `.3` in `%.3d` means that (at least) 3 digits will be printed, with leading zeros if necessary.  The `.3` in `%.3s` means that at most 3 characters of the string will be printed.  See the specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).

Comment: Sorry typo meant "%.3d". Have read stdio man page I got plus some books, but never seen this

Answer (score 0):

Reading each character and checking whether it is a cap allows a split of the names. A quick approach would look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNM 256
#define MAXCH 32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char names[MAXNM][MAXCH] = {{0}};
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[i]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each char in file */
    for (;;) {
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        {
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {     /* if c is Cap,         */
                if (i) names[idx++][i] = 0; /* null-term & new name */
                i = 0;                      /* reset i = 0          */
                if (idx == MAXNM) break;    /* if MAXNM, break      */
            }
            names[idx][i++] = c;            /* add c to name[idx]   */
            if (i == MAXCH) {               /* if MAXCH             */
                names[idx++][i-1] = 0;      /* null-term/trucate    */
                while ((c = getc(fp)) < 'A' || c > 'Z') /* next Cap */
                    {}
                ungetc (c, fp);             /* put it back          */
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (c == EOF) {
            names[idx++][i] = 0;            /* null-terminate last  */
            break;
        }
        if (idx >= MAXNM) break;
    }

    fclose (fp);                            /* close input file     */

    for (c = 0; c < idx; c++)               /* output names         */
        printf ("names[%2d] : %s\n", c, names[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/split_on_caps dat/Capnames.txt
names[ 0] : John
names[ 1] : Frank
names[ 2] : James
names[ 3] : Peter
```

The only thing unclear about your question is whether you prefer to dynamically allocate for each string or whether static declaration suffices. You can clearly allocate a certain number of pointers (e.g. `char *names[MAXNM] = calloc (MAXNM, sizeof *names[0]);`) or you can statically allocate the array as done above. The only difference being you have the ability to reallocate more name pointers in the event you run out.

Comment: Please reparenthesize this loop: `while ((c = getc(fp)< 'A' || c > 'Z'));`, and I much prefer to see the empty loop body on a separate line.  Is there a reason for not using `isupper()`?

Comment: Just found it -- will fix :) Was `gdb`ing myself crazy. No reason, just saves a function call and header file inclusion.